# How do I check if next word from a file in stream isalpha?

Tags: c++

I have a file, InputFile.txt, in the format, `firstname`, `lastname`, `score`:

```
Mike Smith 80
James Jones 75
```

I want to read those values into my c++ program using an ifStream&. This is how I am doing it:

```
std::ifstream inStream("InputFile.txt");

std::string firstname;
std::string lastname;
int score;

while(inStream.peek() != EOF)
{
inStream >> firstname >> lastname >> score;

//further processing ignored for brevity...
}
```

I want to check whether the `firstname` and `lastname` are `isalpha() == true` and that the `score` is all digits (probably with `isdigit()`.

The following approach is not working:

```
    while (inStream >> firstname)
    {
        for (auto element : firstname)
        {
            if (!isalpha(element))
            {
                std::cerr << "Error not a alpha character.";
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Define "not working" - in what case is it giving a wrong result?

Comment: "The following approach is not working"... why? what is it doing that you don't want?

Comment: There are two loops shown that don't match. Please show the code exactly as you are running it.

Comment: It would be easier if you read everything into strings and then test what you read in.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly write

```
while (inStream >> fname >> lname >> score)
{
    //further processing ignored for brevity...
}
```

It will evaluate to implicit true if and only if the whole statement is successfully read. I.e., you don't need to verify that the `score` is a number here. It will be read as a number.

As for the matter of `fname` and `lname`, I would suggest a check something along the lines

```
inline bool is_alpha(const std::string& s) noexcept {
   return std::find_if_not(s.begin(), s.end(),
                           [](unsigned char c) { return std::isalpha(c); }) == s.end();
}
```